# Better way to do conditional django queries

Tags: python, mysql, django

Is there a better way to do the following:

```
    if column_sort == 'size':
        if sort == 'desc':
            results = results.order_by('-size')
        else:
            results = results.order_by('size')
    elif column_sort == 'modified':
        if sort == 'desc':
            results = results.order_by('-last_modified')
        else:
            results = results.order_by('last_modified')
    else:
        if sort == 'desc':
            results = results.order_by('-path')
        else:
            results = results.order_by('path')
    results = results[:100]
```

For example, a way in which to reverse the query order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you just write the code once?

```
valid_column_sorts = ['size', 'last_modified', 'path']

if column_sort in valid_column_sorts:
    if sort == 'desc':
        column_sort = '-' + column_sort
    results = results.order_by(column_sort)
```

Oh yeah, I see that there's some difference between sort fields and values, in which case you need a simple map, like `results.order_by(col_map[column_sort])`

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to use a dict to map the values of `column_sort`:

```
d = {'size': 'size',
     'modified': 'last_modified',
     #... add more items as needed
    }
```

Now you just need to call `get` on the dict, with the second argument specifying a default if the value of `column_sort` isn't in the dictionary:

```
orderby = d.get(column_sort, "path")
```

For the `sort` variable, just add the `'-'` as neccessary:

```
orderby = '-' + orderby if sort == "desc" else orderby
```

And now just execute it:

```
results = results.order_by(orderby)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should word:

```
columns = dict(size='size', modified='last_modified')
column_sort = columns.get(column_sort, 'path')
order = lambda v: '-' if v == 'desc' else ''
results.order_by(order(sort) + column_sort)
```

It will translate user-specified column name to your schema and assume that the default is 'path'.